# Random lag for dynamic content in IIS

Tags: caching, iis, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

I have an ASP.NET web site with a testing page which fetches a few dynamic pages. Usually loading time for all dependencies is very fast:
[image]

But sometimes one or several pages loads much slower than usually:
[image]
This slowdown happens for a random page and randomly in time. After reloading the testing page everything is back to normal.

I do not use any dynamic content caching explicitly, but it seems like usually resources are cached, but something rarely goes wrong.

Also, I put a `StopWatch` to determine the execution time of dynamic pages. The first time after resetting web.config all pages are executed in 20-50 ms and everytime after that (even when this issue with slow page loading happens)  it takes only a 1 ms, so I guess a problem is on the side of IIS. 
What should I check next?

Specs: .NET 4.5, Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 8.5.

Thanks in advance!

**UPD:**
Thanks for your quick responses. The main version for this lag is application pool recycling. I need to mention that the lag happens for each second-third page reload (When I repeatedly click F5). I am almost sure that recycling happens not that often on the server.

Comment: What you are looking for is called "warmup". That is available as a module in IIS 7.5+. In previous versions, you need to execute a warmup script when you start your application, eg after a deployment. This can be something as simple as calling the home page, or hitting a few pages to ensure lookup caches get populated

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the IIS handling of AppDomains. The IIS hosts Apps in AppDomains and within these AppDomains the JIT compiler works like it would with any .NET application. That means the first time a page/controller is used the JIT compiles the code and that takes time. However unlike a local .NET application the IIS occasionally recycles the ApplicationPools which hold the AppDomain to prevent bugs (and free resources) and when you load the page again it has to recompile your App.

Comment: IIS only *recycles* an *application pool* as a precaution against bugs, *not* to conserve resources.

Comment: Depends if you consider a memory leak a bug. :P Never the less I updated my answer. Better?

Comment: Are there any IIS settings to play with to determine that the problem is really about recycling? For example, set a huge timeout and see that this problem does not occur again.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/333907/what-should-i-do-to-make-sure-that-iis-does-not-recycle-my-application

Comment: @Toxantron there's no "depends" about it. Abnormally high CPU or memory usage due to infinite recursion etc *are* bugs. Apache, IIS (all web servers for that matter) have triggers that recycle if a site stays over a threshold for too long and threatens to crash the system

Comment: @VsevolodKrasnov recycling settings aren't related to the *first* page, nor should they be modified without reason. Otherwise a runaway application could freeze your entire server. If an app pool recycles too often, you have a problem that you should check, not cover up

Comment: Man, you don't joke about this, do you? Of course memory leaks **are** bugs. But even if your application is well behaved the IIS will shut it down and this creates different time behavior compared to Apache and PHP for example.

Comment: @VsevolodKrasnov what you are looking for is *warmup*. A warmup module is available in IIS 7.5+. Previous versions require warmup scripts

Comment: @Toxantron no, I just remember when IIS *copied* that behaviour from Apache - it *doesn't* arbitrarily shutdown. Even the TTL for an application first appeared in Apache as a way to catch Heisenbugs - if a site stays alive long enough, recycle it as a precaution against transient problems

Comment: Be that as it may. I still think recycling and JIT compilation is what makes ASP non deterministic regarding page speed. A simple PHP application always responds in a comparable time frame.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Googled warmup and set Start Mode for Application Pool to "AlwaysRunning". It doesn't help, probably I need to do anything more? (Application Initialization module is installed)

Comment: @Toxantron I think after recycling each resource will be loaded in the full cycle - in 300-500 ms, won't it? But in my case the only one or two resources are loading slowly.